# Set Stored Proc variable to result of a call to another Proc

Tags: t-sql

This is why I hate T-SQL.  How the hell do you simply call another proc within a proc.  All I want to do is declare a variable of type varchar(100) and set it to the value returned by executing another stored proc which is returning simply a varchar(100).  I've tried to use EXEC but obviously you can't do that inside a proc and set the result to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy expalains how to do what you want:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data

Comment: awesome, thanks.   Couldn't find a good article out there for some reason

Comment: Normally I find pinal dave (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/author/pinaldave/) to be a good source.  Sprocs can (and should) call sprocs to avoid duplication.